# Entity Framework - Migrate Database from Code in ASP.NET Web Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I currently have an ASP.NET Web Application that connects to a SQL Server database using Entity Framework. The EF migrations are in a separate project in the same solution. Upon application startup, I would like to automatically update to latest using the existing migrations (`AutomaticMigrationsEnabled == false`).

I have the following code in my `WebApiConfig.cs` file:

```
var database = new ApplicationDbContext().Database;

var configuration = new DbMigrationsConfiguration
        {
            TargetDatabase = new DbConnectionInfo(database.Connection.ConnectionString, "System.Data.SqlClient"),
            ContextType = typeof(ApplicationDbContext),
            MigrationsAssembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(ApplicationDbContext)),
            MigrationsNamespace = typeof(ApplicationDbContext).Namespace,
        };

var migrator = new DbMigrator(configuration);
migrator.Update();
```

When I run this, however, I get the following error:

> System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.AutomaticMigrationsDisabledException: 'Unable to update database to match the current model because there are pending changes and automatic migration is disabled. Either write the pending model changes to a code-based migration or enable automatic migration. Set DbMigrationsConfiguration.AutomaticMigrationsEnabled to true to enable automatic migration.'

I know for a fact all my migrations are up to date with the code because if I go to the package manager console and add-migration that way, it provides an empty migration file.

Comment: Depending on your sequence of events, if EF6 sometimes adding that empty migration is the actual solution. Annoying, but how it is.

Comment: I added the blank migration and it still didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  The MigrationsNamespace isn't the same as the namespace of ApplicationDbContext.  I had to explicitly put the namespace where all the migration files reside.  Also, when instantiating the configuration, I had to include the proper context key.  It works now and looks something like this:

```
var database = new ApplicationDbContext().Database;
        var configuration = new DbMigrationsConfiguration
        {
            TargetDatabase =
                                        new DbConnectionInfo(
                                            database.Connection.ConnectionString,
                                            "System.Data.SqlClient"),
            ContextType = typeof(ApplicationDbContext),
            MigrationsAssembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(ApplicationDbContext)),
            MigrationsNamespace = "Prom.Database.Migrations",
            ContextKey = "Prom.Database.Migrations.Configuration"
        };
```